# Is there a big difference in performance (PHP loops)

Tags: php

So, let's say I've got a queryable database with 100 data objects in it. I want to show 3 random ones.

I don't have any working code since this is an idea I just had.

Method 1:

- Query Database for 3 random ids using `mt_rand()`

so essentially `Query for IDs (1, 15, 67)` then print each one.

OR

Method 2:

- Use `mt_rand()` in the loop with a counter (`$counter = 0; $counter = ++$counter)`

essentially `Query ALL posts` if `(ID = 1, 15, 67)` then print each one and if `($counter = 3){ break; }`

Method 2 sounds like it would give me a nasty large object. While Method 1 sounds like it would be a more expensive DB query. I think Method 1 would be better, but I'm not sure

Comment: In Method 1, you cannot be sure an element with that ID exists. Records might be deleted.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: +1, you are right. Also it is cheaper to filter at db level than loop through and all the records and pick up random ones.

Comment: @bažmegakapa It's one [valid] approach of "finding a random element" assuming a "dense distribution within known bounds". For *larger* data-sets, with indices, it is often more efficient than "sorting by RAND": just keep trying until there is a match.

Comment: There's also `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE cond ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;` which is a lot simpler once you have non-sequential IDs (i.e. records deleted)

Comment: @pst Yes, I agree with that. Just noted, so now it's clear that you have to keep trying :).

Comment: @Leigh While simple, that approach does not scale well because the *entire* result-set must be generated *before* the LIMIT is applied ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ID column is indexed, which it probably should be, then doing a select with

```
WHERE id IN (1, 15, 67)
```

is very cheap. And it will scale even if you have many more rows in your table. Solution 2 will not scale as it selects the whole table and loads it into memory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure method 1 is better:

in method 1 the db engine will iterate through all your posts to find the ones you need, then will send only the 3 ones it selected.
in method 2, the db engine will also iterate through all your posts, and then will send a larger object (with all your posts), which will for sure take more time.

hope this was helpfull ;)

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 obviously. It wouldn't be a more expensive DB query if you have indexes set up appropriately.

If you are truly curious, you can find your own answer:

```
<?
$start = microtime();
doMethodOne();
$end = microtime();

echo 'Method 1 took ' . $end - $start . ' ms<br />';

$start = microtime();
doMethodTwo();
$end = microtime();

echo 'Method 2 took ' . $end - $start . ' ms';
```